# What are the possible threats that a waiting pthread_mutex might encounter?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

If a pthread is locking a shared resource.

Is there any threat that a waiting pthread_mutex might encounter?

Something like limitation of parallel pthreads, time limit, event, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the specification, for example [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html), `pthread_mutex_lock()` has a int return value. Apart from the trivial/obvious error causes, such as "invalid argument" etc, there is one which can actually be considered a "threat". Especially a threat to people who do not check return values.

This threat is the return value `EAGAIN` which if not caught properly can cause your program to become faulty, accessing the resource the mutex is supposed to protect while it did not acquire the mutex. `EAGAIN` can happen for example, if the process received a System V "signal" and if this thread with the code is affected by it.

In general, using Unix System V constructs (such as signals) in parallel with Posix threads is at least dangerous. In Unix System V, threads did not exist and it was clear that the single main thread of a process was "interrupted" and used to handle the signal (using a stack-switch to the signal stack). Any kernel side blocking of the main thread got interrupted, the blocking function returns with `EAGAIN` and has to re-issue its call after handling the signal.

Hence, unfortunately the only fool-proof way of coding on Posix/Unix systems involves an abundance of while loops around anything which might block.

```
while( EAGAIN == pthread_mutex_lock(...) );
```

Not doing that would mean that your code can only be used in applications which clearly exert full control over signal behavior. Such as disabling all signals or using other means to ensure that the thread executing this code will not be affected.

Apart from this, Mutexes are system resources (kernel objects) and the amount available is not infinite, yet not usually something to worry about. I hope for other answers to elaborate on such limits.

**EDIT** It seems the documentation has changed in the past few years. Now they state, that EAGAIN would be related to the limit of recursive locks and that `EINTR` shall not happen. In the past, at least there were systems/documentations which conformed with my explanation above.

Also new (at least to me):

> If a signal is delivered to a thread waiting for a mutex, upon return from the signal handler the thread shall resume waiting for the mutex as if it was not interrupted.

Well, maybe they learned something since I last was forced to work with such systems.

Comment: what if EBUSY was returned. what happens to the waiting thread?

Comment: I think EBUSY can only be expected as a result to ``pthread_mutex_trylock()``.

Comment: So, by taking care to EAGAIN, mutex is reliable (i.e. other lock requests won't be dropped). Right?

Comment: Cannot answer that conclusively. I would say you should be very aware of the system(s) you program for. And check if they conform to the latest standards. I used to program such systems (QNX, old linux, newer linux, ...) in the times from 2000-2013 and as I notice now, it is a moving target. But "other mutex dropped" etc. should never happen unless you run on a buggy system or have memory corruption etc.